# Jquery Chosen drop down getting cleared when selecting a particular value

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I have a jquery chosen associated with a country field. It contains country names as options along with an **any** option. If **any** is selected all other selected values from the input text field should be removed and it should show only Any option at that time (in the input text box).

I am using the following code to remove the selected values from the textbox.

```
$("#country option[value='"+selectedoption+"']").remove();
```

The problem is that when any is selected, all other options in the drop down are getting removed. Can anyone help me to solve this. I have shared the code in http://jsfiddle.net/Q52wt/5/.

Answer (score 3):

I made a tiny change, instead of `remove()` I used `prop('selected', false)` and it looks like it is
working fine.

Now looks like this:

```
$("#country option[value='"+selectedoption+"']").prop('selected', false);
```

Check it out now: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q52wt/6/)

Comment: When 'Any' is selected, it is working fine now. But after that, cannot choose any options. I want to choose other options too, after any is chosen.

Comment: To be able to add more options you need to x out the any option. Is not this what you need? .. Otherwise sounds a little bit ambigous

Comment: Upto clicking Any at the first time it is working like what I need. But even after clicking any, I should be able to select other options in drop down list.